# The current URL, , didn't match any of these - using multiple sites

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi, django-wsgi

I wish to have multiple django installations. One at / (which is working fine) and one at /adam. The one at slash adam is redirected by apache correctly, until you try and visit an app. E.g. /admin works but /adam/admin does not work. I get the error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://[CENSORED]/adam/
Using the URLconf defined in bms.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/doc/
^admin/
The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

Notice the empty commas. The apache virtual host is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName [CENSORED]
    DocumentRoot /home/user/bms

    Alias /static/admin/ /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.3-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/media/

    <Directory /home/user/bms/apache>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/ajt1g09/bms/apache>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess bms user=user group=user processes=2 threads=25 python-path=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup bms
    WSGIScriptAliasMatch ^/adam(.*) /home/ajt1g09/bms/apache/django.wsgi
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/bms/apache/django.wsgi

</VirtualHost>
```

And the django.wsgi file in ajt1g09/bms/apache:

```
import os
import sys

path = '/home/ajt1g09/bms'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
sys.path.append('/home/ajt1g09')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'bms.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

And finally, the urls.py file in ajt1g09/bms (clearly showing /admin is there):

> from django.conf.urls.defaults import
>   patterns, include, url
>
> #Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin: from django.contrib
>   import admin
>   admin.autodiscover()
>
> urlpatterns = patterns('',
>       # Examples:
>       # url(r'^$', 'bms.views.home', name='home'),
>       # url(r'^bms/', include('bms.foo.urls')),
>
> ```
> # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
> url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
>
> # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
> url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)), )
> ```

I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: By swapping the alias directives in the virtual host I have managed to get further. There ano longer any empty commas. Instead:

The current URL, adam/admin, didn't match any of these.

This is implying I need to edit every single url in urls.py. Surely this is not the case?

Comment: You shouldn't need to be pointing to a site-packages of a full Python installation. "sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')". This suggests something may be wrong with your mod_wsgi/Python setup if it is required.

Comment: Im pretty sure it is not required

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using:

```
WSGIScriptAliasMatch ^/adam(.*) /home/ajt1g09/bms/apache/django.wsgi
```

Just use:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /adam /home/ajt1g09/bms/apache/django.wsgi
```

The WSGIScriptAliasMatch will not work as written because you haven't re substituted the matched part from back into last argument. Ie.,

```
WSGIScriptAliasMatch ^/adam(.*) /home/ajt1g09/bms/apache/django.wsgi$1
```

You should though simply not be using WSGIScriptAliasMatch. That is for advanced use cases only and requires you be very careful in using it because how you use it can impact what SCRIPT_NAME/PATH_INFO are set to when passed to application and it is those that urls.py matching is based off.

Comment: Hi Graham. With both of your suggestions I get exactly the same error (with apache restart)

Comment: Replace your WSGI script with that documented in 'http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Displaying_Request_Environment' and validate what SCRIPT_NAME and PATH_INFO are that are passed to WSGI application. Post the values of those here.